# Message-info WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Use WooCommerce for digital products and as everyone knows, for this type of product or payment status it is always as processing. To resolve this, use the following code that resolves the issue, but the "payment received successfully" notification message is not synchronized. Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'ts_auto_complete_by_payment_method' );

function ts_auto_complete_by_payment_method( $order_id ) {

    if ( !$order_id ) {

        return;
    }

    global $product;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->data[ 'status' ] == 'processing' ) {

        $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

        if ( $payment_method != "cod" ) {

            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So where you want that msg in admin note section ?

Comment: The notification exists but is not synchronized. Thus, if the customer has the payment approved, he is redirected to a "thank you" page, but the notification is only displayed when the update or page change is made.

Comment: I want the notification to appear immediately on the "thank you" page when payment is confirmed.

Comment: correcting the title: woocommerce-info

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_thankyou', 'update_order_status_and_show_info' );

function update_order_status_and_show_info( $order_id ) {
    if ( !$order_id ) {

        return;
    }


    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->get_status() == 'processing' ) {

        $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

        if ( $payment_method != "cod" ) {

            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
            echo "<span>Payment received successfully.</span>";
        }
    }

}
```

Try this code

Comment: Did not work. We regress. This way the status is not even changed to "completed".

;/

Comment: @JéssicaGarcia - Please try to echo something inside the payment method check if it's entering the condition.